# ListBox icons flick on change when I use multi theme icon code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox

I use this code to do my icons in ListBox are compatible with light theme:

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Margin="4,8,0,2" Width="48" Height="48" VerticalAlignment="Center">
 <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
  <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding itemIcon}" />
 </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

However, when I change listBox.itemsSource ( I need it to change the ListBox content after the user action ) - icons flicks. Actually I see the rectangle and then the icon as the code above do. 
I have tried to animate ListBox (fade out before change itemsSource and fadeIn after), but it looks like the animation is in another thread and not synced with ListBox population. Loaded event fires only once and I can'y use it too.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally decided to use two sets of icons.